# How to pass a list of strings one by one to query() using a function in python?

Tags: python, pandas, function

I want to pass every unique value of a column to a user-defined function one by one and get the results. the unique values are strings and the function is based on query(). below is how I did it and it's not working. i.e I can not pass the 'u' to the query. what is wrong with this code? thx in advance

```
def score_effect(platform):
    df = data.query('platform=="p"')[['sum_of_sales', 'critic_score', 'user_score']]
    plt.figure(figsize=(17,10))
    plt.subplot(1,2,1)
    sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='sum_of_sales', y='critic_score')
    plt.subplot(1,2,2)
    sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='sum_of_sales', y='user_score')
    plt.show()
 
    critic_corr = df.corr().iloc[0,1]
    user_corr = df.corr().iloc[0,2]
    print('Correlation between critic-reviews and sales =', critic_corr)
    print('Correlation between user-reviews and sales =', user_corr)
 
    if critic_corr>0.7:
 
        print('There is a POSITIVE correlation between  critic-reviews and sales')
    else:
        print('There is no significant correlation between critic-reviews and sales')
    if  user_corr>0.7:
        print('There is a POSITIVE correlation between  user-reviews and sales')
    else:
        print('There is no significant correlation between user-reviews and sales')
 
 
 
for p in data['platform'].unique():
    print('Result for:', p)
    score_effect(p)
    print('***************************')
```

Comment: You are passing them but you don't return anything from the function, thus doing nothing with the result within your loop.

Comment: thx @Selcuk. I am new to coding so forgive me if I ask . the code should return a data set right? or should I write "return" at the end?

Comment: A bare `return` will return `None`. You should return whatever the caller needs to get back. In this case you most likely want `return data` but I'm not sure as we don't see the rest of your code. That being said your function doesn't do anything with its argument (`column_unique`) so it always does the same thing whatever you pass to it.

Comment: your solution works like charm! thank u very much for your generous help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should replace

```
data.query('platform=="p"')
```

with

```
data.query('platform == @platform')
```

for starters. The argument to your function is platform, not `p`. `p` is the variable name in your `for` loop but the function scope is different, so your function doesn't have access to `p`.

You should also prefix your variable with an `@` sign as I did above to let `pandas` know that it's a variable and not the string literal "platform". From [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

> You can refer to variables in the environment by prefixing them with an ‘@’ character like `@a + b`.